# Additional Nodes on Galera MySQL failing to add

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera

Ok so I have a second node I am trying to add to a working galera mysql server as another node...configs here

**Node A**(working)

```
[server]
[mysqld]  
[embedded]  
[mysqld-5.5]  
[mariadb]  
binlog_format=ROW  
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=172.16.1.20
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="controller_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://"
wsrep_sst_receive_addres="172.16.1.20"
wsrep_slave_threads=1
wsrep_certify_nonPK=1
wsrep_max_ws_rows=131072
wsrep_max_ws_size=1073741824
wsrep_debug=0
wsrep_convert_LOCK_to_trx=0
wsrep_retry_autocommit=1
wsrep_auto_increment_control=1
wsrep_drupal_282555_workaround=0
wsrep_causal_reads=0
wsrep_notify_cmd=
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=wsrep_sst:password
[mariadb-5.5]
```

**Node B**(wont start)

```
[server]
[mysqld]
skip-name-resolve
log = /var/log/mysqld.log
log-error = /var/log/mysqld.error.log
[embedded]
[mysqld-5.5]
[mariadb]
log = /var/log/mysqld.log
log-error = /var/log/mysqld.error.log
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=172.16.1.21
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="controller_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://172.16.1.20"
wsrep_sst_receive_addres="172.16.1.21"
wsrep_slave_threads=1
wsrep_certify_nonPK=1
wsrep_max_ws_rows=131072
wsrep_max_ws_size=1073741824
wsrep_debug=0
wsrep_convert_LOCK_to_trx=0
wsrep_retry_autocommit=1
wsrep_auto_increment_control=1
wsrep_drupal_282555_workaround=0
wsrep_causal_reads=0
wsrep_notify_cmd=
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=wsrep_sst:password
[mariadb-5.5]
```

**Node A Permissions on /var/lib/mysql**

```
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql     16384 Mar  4 23:54 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql        52 Mar  4 23:54 aria_log_control
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql root     283162 Mar  5 17:49 db01.deg.pod1.err
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql         5 Mar  4 23:54 db01.deg.pod1.pid
-rw-------. 1 mysql mysql 134219040 Mar  5 17:48 galera.cache
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql       104 Mar  5 17:48 grastate.dat
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  12582912 Mar  4 23:54 ibdata1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql   5242880 Mar  4 23:54 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql   5242880 Mar  4 22:30 ib_logfile1
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql      4096 Mar  4 22:59 mysql
srwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql         0 Mar  4 23:54 mysql.sock
drwx------. 2 root  root       4096 Mar  4 22:59 performance_schema
-rw-r--r--. 1 mysql mysql       124 Mar  4 22:11 RPM_UPGRADE_HISTORY
-rw-r--r--. 1 mysql mysql       124 Mar  4 22:11 RPM_UPGRADE_MARKER-LAST
drwxr-xr-x. 2 mysql mysql      4096 Mar  4 22:11 test
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql      4096 Mar  5 17:35 tt
```

**Node B Permissions on /var/lib/mysql**

```
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql     16384 Mar  5 17:49 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql        52 Mar  5 17:49 aria_log_control
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql root          0 Mar  5 17:49 db02.deg.pod1.err
-rw-------. 1 mysql mysql 134219040 Mar  5 17:49 galera.cache
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql       104 Mar  5 17:49 grastate.dat
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  12582912 Mar  5 17:49 ibdata1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql   5242880 Mar  5 17:49 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql   5242880 Mar  5 17:49 ib_logfile1
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql      4096 Mar  4 23:10 mysql
srwxrwxrwx  1 mysql mysql         0 Mar  5 17:49 mysql.sock
-rw-------. 1 root  root        107 Mar  4 23:10 nohup.out
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root     269455 Mar  5 03:42 out.log
drwx------  2 root  root       4096 Mar  5 03:20 performance_schema
-rw-r--r--. 1 mysql mysql       124 Mar  4 22:14 RPM_UPGRADE_HISTORY
-rw-r--r--. 1 mysql mysql       124 Mar  4 22:14 RPM_UPGRADE_MARKER-LAST
drwxr-xr-x. 2 mysql mysql      4096 Mar  4 22:14 test
drwx------  2 mysql mysql      4096 Mar  5 17:36 tt
-rw-------  1 root  root          0 Mar  5 03:52 wsrep_recovery.hh4i9
```

Password is also the same on both ends for mysql user and for root user.

** Failure log on Node B **

```
140305 17:49:39 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140305 17:49:39 mysqld_safe WSREP: Running position recovery with --log_error='/var/lib/mysql/wsrep_recovery.A8nOzH' --pid-file='/var/lib/mysql/db02.deg.pod1-recover.pid'
nohup: ignoring input
140305 17:49:39 [Warning] The syntax '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--general-log'/'--general-log-file' instead.
140305 17:49:39 [Warning] The syntax '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--general-log'/'--general-log-file' instead.
140305 17:49:41 mysqld_safe WSREP: Recovered position bce8f04b-a41a-11e3-b010-4ba4a408598c:0
140305 17:49:41 [Warning] The syntax '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--general-log'/'--general-log-file' instead.
140305 17:49:41 [Warning] The syntax '--log' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--general-log'/'--general-log-file' instead.
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_start_position var submitted: 'bce8f04b-a41a-11e3-b010-4ba4a408598c:0'
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so'
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 25.3.2(r170) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using hardware acceleration.
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_host = 172.16.1.21; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = /var/lib/mysql//galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.size = 128M; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = NO; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 2147483647; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = NO; repl.causal_read_timeout = PT30S; repl.commit_order = 3; repl.key_format = FLAT8; repl.proto_max = 5
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: -1, protocol version: -1
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_sst_grab()
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: Setting initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: protonet asio version 0
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C (optimized) for message checksums.
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: (7036f7c8-a4b8-11e3-97c3-866382997e69, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: (7036f7c8-a4b8-11e3-97c3-866382997e69, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 0
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: PC version 0
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'controller_cluster', peer '172.16.1.20:'
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: declaring 3f183cba-a422-11e3-b1c7-52f230abd39f stable
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: Node 3f183cba-a422-11e3-b1c7-52f230abd39f state prim
140305 17:49:41 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,3f183cba-a422-11e3-b1c7-52f230abd39f,48) memb {
        3f183cba-a422-11e3-b1c7-52f230abd39f,0
        7036f7c8-a4b8-11e3-97c3-866382997e69,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
})
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'controller_cluster'
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 1, memb_num = 2
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete.
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: Waiting for state UUID.
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: 52478b99-a4b8-11e3-9283-8207651d087e
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 52478b99-a4b8-11e3-9283-8207651d087e from 0 (db01.deg.pod1)
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: 52478b99-a4b8-11e3-9283-8207651d087e from 1 (db02.deg.pod1)
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
        version    = 3,
        component  = PRIMARY,
        conf_id    = 47,
        members    = 1/2 (joined/total),
        act_id     = 1,
        last_appl. = -1,
        protocols  = 0/5/2 (gcs/repl/appl),
        group UUID = bce8f04b-a41a-11e3-b010-4ba4a408598c
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [23, 23]
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> PRIMARY (TO: 1)
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required: 
        Group state: bce8f04b-a41a-11e3-b010-4ba4a408598c:1
        Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
140305 17:49:42 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: bce8f04b-a41a-11e3-b010-4ba4a408598c:1, view# 48: Primary, number of nodes: 2, my index: 1, protocol version 2
140305 17:49:42 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
140305 17:49:44 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '172.16.1.21' --auth 'wsrep_sst:password' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --defaults-file '/etc/my.cnf' --parent '13639''
140305 17:49:44 [Note] WSREP: Prepared SST request: rsync|172.16.1.21:4444/rsync_sst
140305 17:49:44 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
140305 17:49:44 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 5 (3, 1)
140305 17:49:44 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 1, protocol version: 3
140305 17:49:44 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
140305 17:49:44 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (bce8f04b-a41a-11e3-b010-4ba4a408598c): 1 (Operation not permitted)
         at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():445. IST will be unavailable.
140305 17:49:44 [Note] WSREP: Node 1.0 (db02.deg.pod1) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0.0 (db01.deg.pod1)(SYNCED) as donor.
140305 17:49:44 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 1)
140305 17:49:44 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 0
140305 17:49:45 [Warning] WSREP: 0.0 (db01.deg.pod1): State transfer to 1.0 (db02.deg.pod1) failed: -1 (Operation not permitted)
140305 17:49:45 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_group.c:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():723: Will never receive state. Need to abort.
140305 17:49:45 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: terminating thread
140305 17:49:45 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: joining thread
140305 17:49:45 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closing backend
140305 17:49:46 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,3f183cba-a422-11e3-b1c7-52f230abd39f,48) memb {
        7036f7c8-a4b8-11e3-97c3-866382997e69,0
} joined {
} left {
} partitioned {
        3f183cba-a422-11e3-b1c7-52f230abd39f,0
})
140305 17:49:46 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
140305 17:49:46 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closed
140305 17:49:46 [Note] WSREP: /usr/sbin/mysqld: Terminated.
140305 17:49:46 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/db02.deg.pod1.pid ended
WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Parent mysqld process (PID:13639) terminated unexpectedly. (20140305 17:49:47.601)
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup. (20140305 17:49:47.603)
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup done. (20140305 17:49:48.110)
```

Comment: Turn on `wsrep_debug` and check the log from that.  There is a problem somewhere in the SST and that log should tell you what it is.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for nodes failing to add is that the existing nodes don't expect them. In your configuration files, you may just need to point each node to the rest.

For example, try using `wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://"172.16.1.20,172.16.1.21"` in both `galera.cnf` files.